# Appending a translated string in html (angular 6) with a property of an object

Tags: html, typescript, angular6, ngx-translate

I have a myapp.component.ts file in which I have the following

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';
import { AuthenticationService } from '/services';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'cd-myapp',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.scss']
   })
export class myAppComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() car: Car;
constructor(
   private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

ngOnInit() {
//my code
 }
}
```

I have another component, in which I have the following in the carhandler.component.ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 
'@angular/core';
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-carhandler',
   templateUrl: './carhandler.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./carhandler.component.scss']
   })
 export class CarhandlerComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() field: string;
 @Input() value: string;

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }}
```

In my myapp.component.html I would like to append. I tried this :

```
<app-carhandler [field]="Testing"
                          [value] = "'DESCRIPTION' | translate" +'-'+{{car.color}}>
      </app-carhandler >
```

It does not work. How should I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, i'm having no explanation why, but it works this way:

```
<app-carhandler [field]="Testing"
                      [value] = "(('DESCRIPTION' | translate) +'-'+ car.color)">
</app-carhandler >
```